# Sort by Activity but don't show Activity in the Results

Tags: javascript, html

I found this jsfiddle that does what I want with one exception. One of the choices to sort by is **Activity**.  I would still like to be able to sort by activity, however I do not want **Activity** to show in the results. Anyone know how to do this?

Here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/omab/kShpU/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/omab/kShpU/2/)

```
 $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        getSortData: {
            name: '.name',
            popularity: '.popularity parseFloat',
            activity: '.activity parseFloat'
        }
    });

 <div class="item well col-sm-3 type-lodge medium-service location-london">
            <h3 class="name">Lion Lodge</h3>
            <p>Popularity: <span class="popularity">1<span></p>
            **<p>Activity <span class="activity">3</span></p>**
            <p class="location">London</p>
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want to change the text in each box to be for example: `"Popularity: 10", "Activity 1", "Liverpool"` to ``"Popularity: 10", "Liverpool"``? Also **Activity** being hidden always or just when it's sorted?

Comment: you could use data attributes to store the activity data

Comment: I want it to look like "Popularity: 10", "Liverpool" in the text box.  Not sure I understand your second question.  I still want to be able to sort by Activity so I want to have an activity number in the code but not show activity in the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need it remove the text "Activity" and the paragraph item, leave just the `<span>`:

```
<p>Activity <span class="activity">...</span></p>
```

To:

```
<span class="activity">...</span>
```

Then in the CSS hide the class `activity`:

```
.activity{ display: none; }
```

You could also add a `class` to the `<p>` an hide that.

[Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kShpU/3/)